# Read error info while API throwing 401 authentication error

Tags: swift, authentication, alamofire

My API returned 401 error while the user token expired or was not valid and it's returning status code 401 and payload with the error message and code like below.

[image]

I want to read this response body while getting 401 errors.

I can able to read status code like below

```
let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse
if let statusCode = response?.statusCode, statusCode == 401 {
   //Retry with new token
}
```

How to read response body message?

Can anyone help me with this?

Through postman (**check above screenshot for reference**) I can see the message and 401 code but on Swift with Alamofire How can I read the message?

EDIT:

I am trying to read this body/data in Request intercpter like below:

```
func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {
    let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse
    if let statusCode = response?.statusCode, statusCode == 401, request.retryCount < retryLimit {
       //Refresh token and retry
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check `response.data`. Then you can need to parse the data.

Comment: I already checked that but response.data is not there in response object :(

Comment: By the way I am checking this in my intercepter where I am trying to retry based on 401 and message combination

Comment: It's in the retry method? Then `if let dataRequest = request as? DataRequest, let data = request.data` is empty?

Comment: Let me check this

Comment: Yes, it's giving me data. Great man! it's working exactly what I want. Thanks a lot for your quick help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTPURLResponse` doesn't have the `data`, but the `request`, as a `DataRequest` has it:

```
if let dataRequest = request as? DataRequest, let data = request.data {
    // parse the data
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help!